# Edison Installation trouble

Tags: intel-edison, dronekit-python

I am trying to install droneapi on my edison, and everything goes fine until the pip install droneapi. protobuf never finds ../src/google/protobuf/unittest.proto I have tried to apt-get python-protobuf 
 and it works, however when loading mavproxy the droneapi module fails when it can't import enum_type_wrapper.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a version mismatch (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239632/how-to-handle-different-versions-of-python-protobuf): What version of protobuf is installed? (You can do "pip freeze" to see.)  What if you "pip install protobuf==2.5.0"?